# Поиск элементов с определёнными потомками

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

Как из множества элементов получить только тот, который содержит нужный мне class name ? Делаю поиск по всем элементам класса team_info. Мне нужно получить целиком весь блок team__info, в котором содержится team__coeff-counter. Если внутри класса team__info нету team__coeff-counter, то пропускать данный элемент.

```
<div class="team__info">
<div class="team__title">Team1</div>
<div class="team__coeff">x1.67
<div class="team__coeff-counter">2</div></div></div>

<div class="team__info">
<div class="team__title">Team2</div>
<div class="team__coeff">x2.22</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи AngleSharp на вашем наборе данных продемонстрирую два подхода.

Данные:

```
    var data = @"<div class=""team__info"">
<div class=""team__title"">Team1</div>
<div class=""team__coeff"">x1.67
<div class=""team__coeff-counter"">2</div></div></div>

<div class=""team__info"">
<div class=""team__title"">Team2</div>
<div class=""team__coeff"">x2.22</div></div>";
    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.Parse(data);
```

Подход 1. Ищем все элементы team__coeff, обходим коллекцию и пропускаем всё, что не имеет team__coeff

```
var result = document.GetElementsByClassName("team__info");
foreach (var element in result)
{
    if(!element.GetElementsByClassName("team__coeff-counter").Any())
        continue;

    // делаем что-то с найденным элементом

    var titleEl = element.QuerySelectorAll(".team__title").FirstOrDefault();
    titleEl.TextContent.Dump();

    var counterEl = element.QuerySelectorAll(".team__coeff-counter").FirstOrDefault();
    counterEl.TextContent.Dump();

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подход 2. Ищем все элементы team__coeff имеющие team__coeff-counter (в выборку попадут элементы team__coeff-counter, поэтому для каждого возьмём parent элемент):

```
var result = document.QuerySelectorAll(".team__coeff .team__coeff-counter");
foreach (var element in result)
{
    // делаем что-то с найденным элементом
    element.Parent.Dump();
}
```

Оба подхода имеют свои плюсы и минусы, оба можно закодировать в HtmlAgilityPack

PS Я туплю. Вон на питоне в удалённом ответе @danilshik - скажите ему спасибо - был самый правильный вариант:

```
var result = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.team__coeff > div.team__coeff-counter");
foreach (var element in result)
{
    // делаем что-то с найденным элементом
    element.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Я делаю поиск по всем элементам, именно FindElements. Но мне нужно выбрать только тот, который внутри себя имеет определенный класс. Привел пример выше. Первый так скажет блок team__info имеет внутри себя класс team__coeff-counter, а второй блок team__info уже не имеет  внутри себя такой класс. Мне нужно выбрать именно по тем критериям, чтобы внутри был определенный класс.

Comment: на Python я бы его нашел так: root.find_element_by_css_selector("div.info")

Comment: @danilshik Если я буду искать только по классу, который мне нужно, я отсекаю возможность получить все данные, которые мне необходимы из всего блока

Comment: @Dmity сначала найдите root - элемент и с помощью css-селектора найдите дочерний класс

Comment: @AK Может быть есть решение с помощью того же HtmlAgilityPack ? Если с селениумом не работаете.

Comment: Я хорошо [умею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A213987+%5Banglesharp%5D) в [AngeSharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anglesharp), хотите? )

Comment: @AK Да, конечно. Вопрос указал в точности, думаю теперь понятно изъяснил. Буду благодарен. Еще раз. Мне нужно выбрать целиком весь блок, который содержит внутри себя нужный мне класс. Если блок не содержит нужного класса, то его не выбирать.

Comment: @Dmitry Обновил ответ. Думаю, что и в HtmlAgilityPack есть аналогичные методы - библиотеки схожие.

Comment: @danilshik Кстати, ваш ответ был совершенно правильный. Я уже успел написать два варианта, но ваш намного лучше. Я его просто вставил в код для anglesharp'а, думаю,что и в HtlAgilityPack легко вставится.

Comment: @AK Спасибо вам большое, все отлично работает. Также спасибо danishik , не успел видимо прочитать. Осталось понять, как из найденных элементов выводить только team_title и остальные нужные теги.

Comment: @AK не подскажите как после вывода нужных блоков, получить нужные классы? например тот же team__title, team__coeff ? Спасибо

Comment: @Dmitry Добавил для первого варианта. А вариант 3 похоже, что нерабочий - я когда начал писать к нему, заметил, что что-то не так - а потом и в документацию полез, там тоже самое написано. Оставил комментарий под ответом danilshik  - завтра ещё раз гляну на свежую голову, может что-то не так понял.

Comment: @AK Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @AK Все равно не понимаю как выбрать Title. У меня получается в блоке team__info есть 2 команды, соответственно 2 тайтла. Если использовать FirstOrDefault как вы показали то выбирается из каждого блока по одному я так понимаю, или вообще только 1 элемент. Как мне из каждого блока вытаскивать team1 title и team2 title ? Может можно без цикла ? Ибо мне придется кучу циклов делать, потому что title это не единственное что мне нужно вытянуть. Спасибо

Comment: @Dmitry Вы противоречите сами себе, потому что у вас в вопросе нарисован team_info в котором только один тайтл. Возможно, вы уже какой-то другой вопрос хотите задать и привести другой пример данных? И не совсем понятно вот что. Если у вас на странице есть блок teams, в нём может быть несколько команд - то как вы планируете без цикла обойтись? И если внутри цикла по командам вам нужны опять-таким множественные элементы - то как опять обойтись без цикла (внутри цикла)?

Comment: @AK Да, в вопросе к сожалению не указал то, что в блоке team__info есть team__title1 для первой команды и team__title1 для второй команды.Просто получается если мне нужно выдернуть 3-4 параметра из блока, то надо внутри цикла, делать много циклов, путанница)

Comment: @Dmitry Давайте отдельным вопросом? Приведите новый фрагмент кода.

Comment: @AK Сделал отдельный вопрос. Если есть возможность помочь, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

На Python, но на C# не трудно переписать:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.team__info > div.team__info")
```

CSS - селектор обозначает, что мы ищем элемент с классом team__info,  у которого есть точно такой же потомок

Comment: Перечитал [доки по дочерним элементам](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/child): всё-таки записи E > F найдутся не элементы E, а элементы F. (И вообще не нашёл в документации, чтобы можно было искат E в похожих селекторах) Так что придётся искать E, а потом итерировать.

Comment: @AK первоначальная задача стояла не много не так. А так вы правы, вернется потомок. Но как вариант этот поиск можно закинуть в try, catch. В try: ниже этого варианта, необходимо найти у нашедшего потомка - родителя. А так как css - селектор позволяет проходить по элементам только вниз, то его можно заменить на XPath, который позволяет проходить в обе стороны

Comment: @AK А если не привязываться к Selenium, то в bs4 вроде есть метод для определения родителя элемента)

Comment: @AK только вроде bs4 нету на c# (Но я могу ошибаться). Возможно там есть и lxml